# Parse Server - Cannot connect to MongoDB in defiance of sharding and replication

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, cluster-computing, sharding, mongodb-replica-set

We deploy a MongoDB Sharded Cluster on AWS with 3 Shards. Each shard has a replicaSet with 3 members, 1 config server and 3 mongos.

```
[ shard 1 ] [ shard 2 ] [ shard 3 ]
[ mongos0 ] [ mongos1 ] [ mongos2 ]
[ config0 ] [ config1 ] [ config2 ]
[ (p) md0 ] [ (s) md0 ] [ (s) md0 ]
[ (s) md1 ] [ (p) md1 ] [ (s) md1 ]
[ (s) md2 ] [ (s) md2 ] [ (p) md2 ]
```

and here how shards are distributed on the 3 EC2 instances

```
[   md0   ][   md1   ][   md2   ]
[ shard 1 ][ shard 1 ][ shard 1 ]
[ shard 2 ][ shard 2 ][ shard 2 ]
[ shard 3 ][ shard 3 ][ shard 3 ]
[ mongos0 ][ mongos1 ][ mongos2 ]
[ config0 ][ config1 ][ config2 ]
```

You can see that the replicaSet members are not on the same instance.

But when for example `md0` goes down, our API (Parse Server) loose connection with the Cluster, althougth `md1` and `md2` are still alive and already elected a new primary. All EC2 instances hold a copy of  all collections including sharded collections thanks to replication.

the connection string looks like this

```
mongodb://user:password@mongos0:27017,mongos1:27017,mongos2:27017/mydb
```

do you think is it an issue with the configuration of the Cluster/Shard or is it a problem related to the API, which keep connection instead of trying to connect to the other mongos ?

Comment: Can you show the connection string which your API (Parse Server) is using to connect? Possibly it isn't connecting to the replica set properly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - it seems to be an issue with mongoose and possible bug.https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3634